# How to upload a blob with Multer?

Tags: node.js, blob, html5-audio, multer

I have been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qzmri1WaaE) in order to know how to use `Multer` to upload files.

I have then implemented an image-upload feature in one `Node.js` app of mine.

Now I would like to use `Multer` to upload the contents of a blob containing audio data. What is the way to go? I already tried a bit following what I learned, but I already have some issues:

1. I am now dealing with audio data instead of graphic data.
2. I do not have a field name any more to put as an argument for the *multer({ storage: storage }).single(...);* function call.

I hope someone with experience (using `Multer`) will provide some guidance on this.

For reference, here is my code for when the upload button is clicked:

```
uploadVceRcd.onclick = e => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var fd = {};
        fd["fname"] = "VoiceRecord_"+Date.now()+".opus";
        fd["data"] = event.target.result;
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'VoiceUpLoad',
          id: document.getElementById('sentID').innerText,
          data: fd,
          dataType: 'text'
        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log('uploadAudio - Done !');
          console.log(data);
        });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

And here is my code for handling the matching VoiceUpLoad route inside index.js:

```
app.post('/VoiceUpLoad', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
        console.log('A Multer error occurred when uploading. !!!');
      } else {
        // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
        console.log('A unknown error occurred when uploading. !!!');
        console.log(err);
      }
    } else {
      // Everything looks fine.
      console.log('All seems OOKK !!!');
      console.log(req.file);

      if (req.file == undefined) {
        console.log('req.file == undefined!!!');
      } else {
        console.log('SHOULD BE OOKK !!!');

        .......
      }
    }
  });
});
```

When I run this code I get the following in the logs:

```
... app[web.1]: All seems OOKK !!!
... app[web.1]: undefined
... app[web.1]: req.file == undefined!!!
```

Comment: Do you have an idea about the codec of this audio?

Comment: It is OPUS, hoping this is the answer you want to know.

Comment: is this a live audio stream or something you got from a file reader or any other stream reader?

Comment: It is something I got from the local microphone and the recording is finished.

Comment: did you try the solution, and is it working?

Comment: I am on the process of trying your solution. For the time being it does not work. On Firefox, in the web console debugger I can see this message "ReferenceError: recordRTC is not defined" and the program is stopped at the line containing "recordRTC.getBlob()".

Comment: Oh im sorry I have to edit the answer

Comment: Please see the edited answer

Comment: I tried the modified version and the previous issue disappeared. But the problem is still not solved. I still see the exact same 3 lines (mentioned at the end of my post). And by the way you do not write what I shoud do about the "multer({ storage: storage }).single(...); function call", that is the 2nd issue mentioned in my post. This could be the detail missing for it to work, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code to upload the audio file,

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fname', "VoiceRecord_"+ Date.now() + ".opus")
    formData.append('data', event.target.result)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'some/path',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log('uploadAudio - Done !');
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Please try this I will explain it if it works.